# hgsubversion fails with "no module named repo"

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion

I updated my Ubuntu installation which updated my mercurial version, and now hgsubversion doesn't work anymore. I keep getting an error that says "abort: No module named repo!" My copy of hgsubversion seems to be up to date with http://hg.durin42.com/hgsubversion/.

Answer (score 0):

hgsubversion doesn't seem to be actively maintained, but the error wasn't too hard to fix. Taking a look at the relevant source file shows that this error isn't the real error, but is from attempting to recover from the real error. Apparently `repository` was moved from `mercurial` into `mercurial.interfaces`, so changing the line above `peerapi=1` to `from mercurial.interfaces.repository import peer as peerrepository` resolves the issue. I would file a bug report, but I was unable to find a place to report it, so I put it here.

Edit: Right, the file in question that needed editing was hgsubversion/svnrepo.py

Answer (score 0):

> My copy of hgsubversion seems to be up to date with http://hg.durin42.com/hgsubversion/

You have to use good and correct location as source of extension:

- hg.durin42.com/hgsubversion **is not maintained** at least 18 months

<strike>* real hgsubversion repository now is at https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git</strike>

- tip of *this repo* is a lot fresher and have all fixes, needed for HG v5

`>hg log -r tip --style compact`

`1702[tip]   d6ac1ae9027a   2020-08-04 00:23 +0200   a`

`gitnodekw: do not crash on hg incoming when log template includes gitnode()`

On the rights of idea: you try to use [TortoiseHG](https://launchpad.net/%7Etortoisehg-ppa) on your Ubuntu, which seems to have slightly more newest hgsubversion in library

Comment: That appears to be a hg-git extension instead of a hg-svn one. Can you use that extension on an svn repository?